# How to make dynamic css colours in flask

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

In my app.py, I have a list of distionaries like: `list=[{'grade':0,'colour':(0,0,0)},{'grade':10', colour':(0,0,0)},{'grade':5',colour':(0,0,0)}`, where grade can be anywhere between 0 and 10. (Some keys are removed to provide simplicity).
I then assign each item a colour based on their grade like this: (using rgb(red,green,blue) format)

```
for i in list:
    green = i['grade'] * 25.5
    red = 255 - green 
    i['colour'] = (red,green,0)
```

and my flask route:

```
@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    return render_template('dashboard.html', list=list)
```

My dashboard.html file contains

```
{% block content %}
  {% for i in list %}
    <h3 style="color:rgb({{i['color']}});text-align:center;">{{i['grade']}} </h3>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

However, this does not work the same way as `<h3 style="color:rgb(255,0,0)>`, and it throws errors stating `) expected, at-rule or selector expected, { expected, at-rule or selector expected` 
I am looking for any way or workaround around this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color values you generate are part of a tuple. To use this in the CSS statement, you should concatenate the sequence into a string using a delimiter. The jinja filter `join` is suitable for this.

When choosing your variable names, keep in mind that you could cover up existing keywords.

```py
@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():

    items=[
        {'grade':0,'colour':(0,0,0)},
        {'grade':10, 'colour':(0,0,0)},
        {'grade':5, 'colour':(0,0,0)}
    ]
    
    for item in items:
        green = item['grade'] * 25.5
        red = 255 - green 
        item['colour'] = (red,green,0)
    
    return render_template('dashboard.html', **locals())
```

```html
{% for item in items %}
<h3 style="color: rgb({{ item.colour | join(',') }});">{{ item.grade }}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same errors as mentioned previously; the at-rule or selector expected, i think the fact that rgb is a function  makes it not like the {{ }} brackets

Comment: Actually, I dont think any part of style can take in variable brackets

Comment: Jinja is rendered server-side and CSS is only interpreted in the browser, so it should work, which it does for me. I can imagine that your development environment doesn't like the syntax, which doesn't change the way it works.

Comment: Ah, you are correct, it doesnt like the syntax but it still works! Thanks for the help!